# Modx ifempty then else statements

Tags: modx

Currently the code below will only show the HeroImage if one exists.  If one doesn't exist, it doesn't show the other image blogImage.  How can I change the code to show blogImage, if there is no HeroImage.  Thanks

```
  <img src="[[*HeroImage:isempty:then='[[*blogImage:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]] [[*]]':else='[[*HeroImage:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]] [[*]]']]" alt="[[*pagetitle]]" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: You need to use backticks.

Comment: look at the :default option

Answer (score 1):

Using the `:default` option should be enough:

```
[[*HeroImage:default=`[[*blogImage]]`:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ifempty and (default, empty, isempty) works like default value if input not specified else it returns the input value itself. So second else statement has no meaning and doesn't work.

For your purpose you can use "is" modifier like

```
[[*HeroImage:is=``:then=`[[*blogImage:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]]`:else=`[[*HeroImage:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]]`]]
```

And keep in mind using back-ticks for modx templating

Answer (score 0):

I'd roll this a slightly different way, but it's likely the same result:

``` [[*HeroImage:neq=``:then=`[[*HeroImage:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]]`:else=`[[*blogImage:phpthumbof=`w=1200&h=800`]]`]] ```